# MySQL stored procedure return variable values from seconds query?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

```
SET @v1 = '';
SET @v2 = '';

SET @Query = CONCAT('SELECT sum(colName1), sum(colName2) INTO @v1, @v2 FROM tableName WHERE id=1 ');
PREPARE stmt FROM @Query;

EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

SET @Query = CONCAT('SELECT id, name, ? as value1, ? as value2 FROM tableName WHERE id=1 ');
PREPARE stmt FROM @Query;

EXECUTE stmt USING @v1, @v2;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

While reading values in ASP.Net the value in byte array.

**ERROR 
Exception: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Byte[]' to type 'System.IConvertible'.**

How can I get the value of @v1 and @v2.

Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value of @v2 get NULL from first query that why the second query stored procedure query not return any thing.
so check the value IS NULL by

```
IF @v2 IS NULL THEN
    SET @v2 = 0;
END IF;
```

Then stored procedure return the result set